# How to mock the mongodb Fluent Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, moq

Below is the sample code I would like to mock the fluent result using Moq.

database.GetCollection(nameof(Collection)).Aggregate().
Match(x => x.IsActive)
.Unwind(x => x.PersonalDetails, new AggregateUnwindOptions { PreserveNullAndEmptyArrays = false })
.Project(x => new ResultModel
{
Firstname = x.FirstName,
Lastname = x.LastName
}

Comment: It's not recommended to mock third party libraries. You should mock your wrapper over the above query

Comment: @dododo didn't get your point and this code is c# aggregate Fluent Query.

Comment: It's a bad practice to mock code that you don't own. Instead you should just create a method (like in repository pattern) and then mock this method itself.